# Akka Actors and Supervising Child Actors

Tags: akka

I have a supervisor actor that does the context.actorOf(...) and creates child actors as below:

```
class MySupervisorActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val allActors: MyActors = ActorConfig(context.system.settings.config, context)

  context watch allActors.userActor
  context watch allActors.notifyActor

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    .....
  }
}
```

My question is, are my UserActor and NotifyActor childrens of MySupervisorActor? All what I'm doing is, wrapping the created Actors in a case class which looks like this:

```
MyActors(userActor: ActorRef, notifyActor: ActorRef)
```

The ActorConfig simply uses the supplied context and does context.actorOf(...) to create the set of ActorRef's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child actors are created using the context implicit that is available within the scope of each Actor. So in your case, the heirarchy of the created actors would be as:

```
/user
  supervisorActor
    userActor
    notifyActor
```